# Unable to go to tags while editing a file in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm editing a source file in Vim, and in the middle of it I want to search for a tag (to understand some variable/class/method etc.), and I click `Ctrl+]` to look for the tag, and if the tag is supposed to be in a different file, it doesn't allow me to move away from the current file because it is being **edited** - it displays the usual Vim error - "E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)"

The workaround I have is to save the file first and re-open it and then look for the tag.

Is there a way to search the tags without having to save and reopen the file.

Comment: Are you using `:wq` to save? Because that also closes the file. Just do `:w` to save, then do the `ctrl + ]` for ctags

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was hooked to ":wq". This would make much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following line in your `vimrc` to allow Vim to edit another buffer without having to write the current one:

```
set hidden
```

See `:help 'hidden'`.

If you don't want to set that option, the alternative would be to use `<C-w>]`, which opens the tag in a new window. See `:help ctrl-w_]`.

Note that, as pointed out in a comment, you don't have to write and quit the current buffer in order to jump to a tag: writing it is enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and multiple suggestions. 
They all work great, though opening in new tab is quite good.